# PHP how to declare object like $foo->$bar->$car

Tags: php, oop

I need to use an object like $foo->$bar->$car, where $bar and $car can assume a lot of values. How can I declare it?

For example, I need to say:

```
$foo->{'0'}->{'a'} = 2;  
$foo->{'0'}->{'b'} = 4;  
$foo->{'1'}->{'a'} = 8;
```

**edit:**
$bar and $car can assume a lot of values each.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: instead of an object within an object within an object, wouldn't that be a perfect case for an array of objects?

Comment: I did not think of that. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike with arrays, PHP will not auto-instantiate "missing" objects for you:

Array:

```
php > var_dump($x);
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: x in php shell code on line 1
NULL
php > $x[1][2][3] = 'hi mom';
php > var_dump($x);
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      [3]=>
      string(6) "hi mom"
    }
  }
}
```

Object:

```
php > var_dump($y);
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: y in php shell code on line 1
NULL
php > $y->x->y = 'hi dad';
PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in php shell code on line 1
```

You **MUST** define each intermediate object yourself:

```
php > $y = new stdClass();
php > $y->x = new stdClass();
php > $y->x->z = new stdClass();
php > var_dump($y);
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["x"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["z"]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```